# Setting a maxDate for boostrap datepicker with ERB rails 4 and t.text-field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

In my javascript console, this worked as expected, setting the max date of the datepicker to today

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker('setEndDate', '2018-03-19');
```

Putting this in my rails erb template,

```
<%= f.text_field :date, class: 'form-control datepicker', value: Date.today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') %>
<script>$('.datepicker').datepicker('setEndDate', '<%= Date.today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') %>');</script>
```

... the date goes back to February year 19 and doesn't let me pick a date, as if it's misinterpratating the date format.

I'm using the date format as set in admin_lte.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Bootstrap Datepicker
  $('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    orientation: 'bottom'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the javascript call in a `$(document).ready(function()`:

```
<%= f.text_field :date, class: 'form-control datepicker', value: Date.today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') %>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function()  {
                $('.datepicker').datepicker('setEndDate', '<%= Date.today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') %>');
                });

</script>
```